# Alpine Linux apk: List out directly installed packages by `apk add`?

Tags: alpine

Is it possible to list packages directly installed by `apk add`? e.g. `apk add docker`, `apk add lm-sensors file`, etc.

Running `apk info` lists ALL installed packages (including dependencies of installed packages), but I want to narrow this list down to top-level packages that are not dependencies of other packages in order to reproduce these packages on another system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list should be automatically generated and available at `/etc/apk/world`. See `apk-world(5)`:

> At /etc/apk/world, apk maintains the world, or list of explicitly
> installed packages. This is a plaintext file with one package spec per
> line.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tool.

You should [use `lbu`](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Alpine_local_backup) to generate a package list or better yet an overlay file which you can use to bring an Alpine Linux system to a known set of packages.